# check updates on each subfolder of subfolders dcmp python

Tags: python, backup, shutil, os.path

I am trying to build a back-up script in order to back-up all my pc to an external ssd(lost all my data 3 times by now).

It works great for the files and main folders but until now I am not able to check if there were any updates on the subfolders.

The logic is this:
We have 1 source folder and 1 destination folder. If we have a new folder or a new file created in the source folder, copy it to the destination folder. If we have a new or modified file or folder inside any subfolder, copy what is new or modified to the same path in the destination folder.

Example:

```
dir_src = r"C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\x"
dir_dst = r"C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\y"
```

This work perfect, if I have a new or modified file or folder in source folder.

But, here is the tricky part: if I have a new or modified file or folder in C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\x\w\a or C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\x\w\a\new.txt the code won't get it, it just stuck to the main hierarchy. I do not want to copy the entire folder (100gb+) for a modified file or folder that has maybe 7kb because it will take more time than needed.

Attaching the entire code below:

```
import os, shutil
import os.path, time
import filecmp
from filecmp import dircmp

fob = open(r"C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\log.txt", "a")
dir_src = r"C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\x"
dir_dst = r"C:\Users\UNIX\Desktop\backup\y"

left_folder = []
right_folder =[]

def start_log():
    fob.write("\n")
    fob.write("===============")
    fob.write("Started at:      %s" % time.strftime("%c"))
    fob.write("\n")

def write_log():
    fob.write("File name:       %s" % os.path.basename(pathname))
    fob.write("     Last modified date:     %s" %time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(pathname)))
    fob.write("     Copied on:      %s" % time.strftime("%c"))
    fob.write("\n")

def print_diff_files(dcmp):
    global name, left_folder, right_folder, left_file, right_file
    for name in dcmp.diff_files:
        left_file = f"{dcmp.left}\{name}"
        right_file = f"{dcmp.right}\{name}"
        left_folder.append(left_file)
        right_folder.append(right_file)
    for sub_dcmp in dcmp.subdirs.values():
        print_diff_files(sub_dcmp)

start_log()

for w in os.listdir(dir_src):
    name = ""
    pathname = os.path.join(dir_src, w)
    try:
        spathname = os.path.join(dir_dst, w)
        if os.path.isdir(spathname):
            dcmp = dircmp(pathname, spathname)
            print_diff_files(dcmp)
            if name != "":
                for file in left_folder:
                    shutil.copy2(left_file, right_file)
                    write_log()
                    print("New folder version added: " + str(pathname))
                    print(f"Modified files: {right_file}")
        elif not filecmp.cmp(pathname, spathname):
            shutil.copy(pathname, dir_dst)
            write_log()
            print("New file version added: " + str(spathname))
    except:
        if os.path.isdir(pathname):
            shutil.copytree(pathname, spathname, dirs_exist_ok=True)
            write_log()
            print("New folder added: " + str(spathname))
        else:
            spathname = os.path.join(dir_dst, w)
            shutil.copy(pathname, dir_dst)
            write_log()
            print("New file added: " + str(spathname))
fob.close()

print("Done")
```

Comment: You've already lost your data 3 times and instead of using a tried and tested backup solution you want to create your own backup software and logic in python? You'd want asoftware that can do `incremental backups`.

Comment: @Daviid you are right, but it's also a learning to work with subdirectories method. In the long run, I agree that I should choose a proper software for this.

Comment: Well, after `dcmp = dircmp(pathname, spathname)` you treat everything as files but `dircmp` returns files and directories, overall, you should create a function that takes a source directory and gets all files from that directory, if it finds a directory it should call itself with that directory, that way this recusrsive function will call itself until no more folders are found, then it'll return. Like going down branches of a tree to find all leaves. At the end you should be left with an array of ONLY files. Then you check if those files have been changed from the destination folder.

Comment: Or you could check if they're new/different from dest folder before adding them to the files array.